# Поднять тост – это правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос был задан (даже дважды) на одном из форумов, и все участники  (6 человек) отвечали, что **так нельзя говорить**.

Например: "В выражении "поднять тост" заключается очень распространенная речевая лексическая ошибка. Слово "тост" обозначает небольшую заздравную речь в честь юбиляра, именинника и т.д. Правильно - произнести тост, провозгласить тост".

**Но в словаре Кузнецова такое выражение считается корректным.**

Из словаря:
ТОСТ, -а; м. [англ. toast] Застольное пожелание, предложение выпить вина в честь кого-, чего-л.; здравица. Провозгласить, произнести т. Поднять т. Выпить т. за здоровье хозяйки дома.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поднять тост — правильно. Обычная метонимия. Съесть три тарелки можно — почему перед этим нельзя поднять тост?..

*...За хороший аппетит!*